# Pandas - mapping ids between Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes I need to map.

`df_players`:

```
name            711 non-null object
player_id       711 non-null int64
round_id       711 non-null int64
team_id         711 non-null int64
```

`df_games`:

```
game_id         10 non-null int64
team_home_id    10 non-null int64
team_away_id    10 non-null int64
```

Now I need to bring home or away info from `df_games` to my `df_players`, adding value 1 if team played home, or 0 if team played away.

---

I am trying add a column home and one away to `df_players`, like so:

```
df_players['home'] = df_players['team_id'].map(df_games['team_home_id'])
df_players['away'] = df_players['team_id'].map(df_games['team_away_id'])
```

But I'm getting all `NaN`.

How do I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not map , check with `isin`

```
df_players['home'] = df_players['team_id'].isin(df_games['team_home_id'])
df_players['away'] = df_players['team_id'].isin(df_games['team_away_id'])
```

Comment: nice, and I will get a boolean for each value, right?

Comment: @8-BitBorges you can add astype(int) at the end